# Is this sentence correct in this situation?

Tags: sentence-construction

If I happened to be in an uncomfortable situation where, for example, somebody would be speaking about something that I did and I was ashamed of it, could the following sentence be correct?

- *While the history progressed I felt like myself as If was shrinking
  more and more*

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence would need to change either to:

> While the story progressed I felt myself shrinking more and more.

or:

> While the story progressed I felt as if I was shrinking more and more.

The "history" you are thinking of is the story being recounted by the teller, which made you feel like you were "shrinking" due to shame.